# Python Validate_Email Doesn't work when pulling from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

Basically, if I create an array of strings and iterate through the array with the method... everything comes out perfectly.

However, If I grab them from my db.... even though I've checked the type and even printed out the emails to the console... it still shows emails failing validation even though if I manually do it as a string it works fine

```
import pymongo
import validate_email
import unicodedata
from pymongo import MongoClient
from validate_email import validate_email
# Mongo Info
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.EmailList
emails = db.Emails

emailsToVerify = ['harry@mail.com', 'buzzard@gmail.com', 'frank@Einstein.com']

def verifyEmail(emailToVerify):
    for item in emailToVerify:
        print validate_email(item)

def grabTenEmails():
    i = 0

    for email in emails.find():
        if i < 3:
            i += 1
            # encode('utf8')
            uEmail =  str(email['email'])
            print(uEmail + ' has type ' + str(type(uEmail)))
            emailsToVerify.append(uEmail)

# collection.remove({"email": uEmail})
print('Grabbing ten emails...')
grabTenEmails()
verifyEmail(emailsToVerify)
```

There's the code. not sure what's up. I have messed with this for a bit... so if it looks like I'm doing retarded stuff, it's because I've tried quite a few things.

output of `print('rep : ' + uEmail.__repr__())`

```
rep : 'aRealEmail@yahoo.com\r'
```

Comment: I don't have a mongodb (in order to replcate the issue), would you mind to update the question with the output of `uEmail.__repr__()`?

Comment: when I added that and ran it... it works now... idk wtf

Comment: Well... Stackoverflow sometimes works as a [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). :-)

Comment: Okay, sorry It wasn't... it was responding to my custom array. I was seeing the results to `verifyEmail()` since it was a custom array of strings

Comment: Added output requested

Comment: you have a double import for validate_email, remove the `import validate_email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a new line character at the end of the email string (the `\r` stuff). Chop it of with:

```
uEmail =  str(email['email']).strip()
```

or:

```
print validate_email(item.strip())
```

Comment: Glad to be helpful. The print statement is tricky because some white space characters will not be evident, the `__repr__()` method is valuable when debugging strings.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that validate_email does not work correctly, just checks the exact address part; you might want to clean the mail first using the stdlib function [`email.utils.parseaddr(address)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr)

```
>>> import email.utils
>>> email.utils.parseaddr('aRealEmail@yahoo.com\r')
('', 'aRealEmail@yahoo.com')
>>> email.utils.parseaddr('Bill Gates <billyboy@hotmail.com>')
('Bill Gates', 'billyboy@hotmail.com')
```

Comment: Good idea. And I agree the library isn't the best at all. Would love it to actually be working!

Comment: technically for example, `'Bill Gates <billyboy@hotmail.com>'` is an email address, not just the part in the brackets.

Comment: Definitely. The cool thing though is that you could get their name separated and then use that dynamically for whatever you're creating. Like `Hello [[name]],` or whatever.